# http header response 400

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, ionic-framework

Hi  I try to consume  api rest But I can not send the header correctly I have an error 400 that tells me that the body of the request is not valid, it has been treated in many ways and I think the problem is the header.
they ask me to send the Public-Merchant-Id in the headers y try this:

```
KushkiS: function(card,cvc,total) {
            console.log(card,cvc,total);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var req = {
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'https://api-uat.kushkipagos.com/v1/tokens',
             headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Public-Merchant-Id:1000000243'
             },
             request: {
                  "card": {
                    "name": card.data.nombre,
                    "number": card.data.number.toString(),
                    "expiryMonth": "02",
                    "expiryYear": "21",
                    "cvv": cvc
                  },
                  "totalAmount": total,
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "isDeferred": false
                }

            };
            $http(req).then(function(responseData){
                console.log(responseData);
                deferred.resolve(responseData);

            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
```

### The information of the api contains this:

### Public-Merchant-Id  header  string

### request             body

```
{
  "card": {
    "name": "Lisbeth Salander",
    "number": "4242424242424242",
    "expiryMonth": "02",
    "expiryYear": "21",
    "cvv": "123"
  },
  "currency": "USD"
}
```

Comment: for `RESTful API` it's better if you use [Http-Rest-Service](https://github.com/maherAshori/Http-Rest-Service)

Comment: Maybe you need to check CORS. Refere to this [Code Sample](http://www.code-sample.com/2015/02/enabling-cors-in-angularjs.html?m=1)

Comment: can you please set `'Content-Type': "application/json"` in the header, i think you miss it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missing `content type`, you can pass `headers` using config object.

```
   var data = {};

   var config = {
      headers : {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Public-Merchant-Id:1000000243'

      }
    }

    $http.post(url, data, config).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //do something
     }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        //do something
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the service is expecting 'Public-Merchant-Id' header but you are passing 'Authorization' header.

```
headers: {  'Public-Merchant-Id':'1000000243' }
```

Contact with your service provider or go through the Api documentation to get details about how to use them correctly.